# How to change Xcode Preview position side to right side?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uikit, position, preview

[image: xcode preview position giridharan venkatapathy]

Having trouble not able to move the preview of Xcode from the bottom to the right.

Answer (score 68):

For people who wanted to move preview it to the right side... Change Layout (right corner of workspace second last option) to "Canvas on Right"

[image: xcode preview position giridharan venkatapathy]

Comment: Really annoying. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does not appear to work with Xcode 14.

Comment: Need to got o Editor Menu  -> Layout

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Show or Hide inspector in the top right corner of the Xcode window.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot to make the answer easy to read.